# Alternative definitions of posterior probability

Tags: probability, bayesian, posterior

This is a follow-up from [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/314807/29911).

In the [cited article](https://bmcsystbiol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1752-0509-7-25), which uses a bayesian framework to identify prioritized gene lesions, one posterior is defined as the following:

$$P(D|S) \quad \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \quad ∑_iP(D|M_i)·P(M_i|S) \tag{1}$$

which translates to "the posterior that the gene $D$ is a driver gene, assuming that the gene set $S$ expresses the phenotype (i.e. has a driver gene), is defined as the posterior that $D$ is a driver given that $M_i$ is a driver, multiplied with the posterior that $M_i$ is a driver given that $S$ has a driver gene".

Aside from the biological definitions (gene, lesion, driver, gene set), it is not clear to me how this relate to the Bayes theorem, i.e.

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)} \tag{2}$$

which is used to compute the posterior. Is posterior a generic term with alternative definitions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$P(D|S) \quad \underline{deff} \quad ∑_iP(D|M_i)·P(M_i|S) \tag{1}$$

is just a consequence of [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability):

$\begin{align*}
P(D|S) &= \sum_{i}P(D,M_i | S)\\
&= \sum_{i} \frac{P(D, M_i, S)}{P(S)}\\
&= \sum_{i} \frac{P(D | M_i, S)P(M_i, S)}{P(S)}\\
&= \sum_{i} \frac{P(D | M_i, S)P(M_i| S)P(S)}{P(S)}\\
&= \sum_{i} P(D | M_i, S)P(M_i| S)\\
\end{align*} $

where $S = \{M_1, M_2, \dots, M_t\}$

Comment: You might want to answer the O.P.'s question directly - "No, the posterior is not a generic term with alternative definitions.  Here's why not:" for example.

Comment: I am unsure of the priority of ',' and '|' as operators, if I remember correctly '|' has higher priority. Should the first line be read as "Joint probability of $D$ and ($M_i$ given $S$)"?

Comment: Priority? The order is immaterial here.

Comment: @rightskewed Sorry, I didn't get it. How can the order be immaterial in $P(D,M_i|S)$?

Comment: $P(A,B) = P(A\cap B)$. It's like an 'and' operation.

Comment: @rightskewed Thanks. Now I see that it's immaterial. I thought I read somewhere that order was important. But actually if you try to derive $\sum_i \frac{P(D,M_i,S)}{P(S)}$ from $\sum_i P(D,M_i|S)$ you obtain the same derivation with both interpretations.